# Does $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{n} \ln(2 \cosh(nx))$ converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{n} \ln(2 \cosh(nx)).$ It is clear that pointwise $f_n(x) \rightarrow |x|$ on all of $\mathbb{R}.$

However, I fail to see if this convergence is also uniform. I am grateful for any insight on this issue.

Differentiation of $f_n$ yields $f_n'(x)=\tanh(nx)$ but that does not lead to immediate further consequences, so I am stuck a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$0\le \frac{\log(2\cosh(nx))}{n}-|x|=\frac1n\log(1+e^{-2n|x|})\le \frac1n$$